# FOR /F batch file loop not running

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, service, remote-desktop

I am attempting to create this batch file, I want it to check a remote system for a service if it has the service check to make sure it is running if it is not running start the service; if the service is not installed, install it. I have this working on a system by system basis. What I would like to do is make it so I can have it draw the system to be tested name from a list using the FOR /F command

Here is what I have so far.

```
    @echo off

    SET InputFile=C:\Users\locationoffile\complist.txt

    :FOR

    FOR /F "delims= " %%i IN (%InputFile%) DO SET comp=%%i

    :PING

    ECHO %comp%

    ping -n 1 %comp% | FIND "TTL="

    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :FAILED 

    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO :SERVICECHECK

    :SERVICECHECK

    SC \\%comp% QUERY ServiceName > Null
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1060 GOTO INSTALL
    ECHO EXISTS
    GOTO STATE

    :STATE

    ECHO Checking Service State

    sc \\%comp% query ServiceName | findstr /i "STATE"

    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO :START

    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :EOF

    :START

    ECHO Starting Service

    psexec \\%comp% net start ServiceName

    GOTO :FOR

    :INSTALL

    ECHO Installing ServiceName

    psexec.exe -s \\%comp% \\locationoffile/filename.exe /S /v /qn

    GOTO :FOR

    :FAILED

    ECHO Failed to connect

    GOTO :FOR
```

This pulls the first line item from the list runs the rest of the batch and then stops, it doesn't move on to the next name in the list the batch just ends. Here is the original "Working" batch file.

```
    @echo off

    ECHO Enter Computer Name
    set /p comp=

    ping -n 1 %comp% | FIND "TTL="

    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :FAILED

    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO :SERVICECHECK

    :SERVICECHECK
    SC \\%comp% QUERY ServiceName > Null
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1060 GOTO INSTALL
    ECHO EXISTS
    GOTO STATE

    :STATE
    ECHO Checking Service State

    sc \\%comp% query ServiceName | findstr /i "STATE"

    IF ERRORLEVEL 0 GOTO :START

    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :EOF

    :START
    ECHO Starting Service

    psexec \\%comp% net start ServiceName

    GOTO :EOF

    :INSTALL

    ECHO Installing Service Name

    psexec.exe -s \\%comp% \\locationoffile/filename.exe /S /v /qn

    GOTO EOF

    :FAILED

    ECHO Failed to connect

    :EOF

    ECHO END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proper use of a for-loop is:

```
for ..... do (
  a command
  another command
)
```

But attention: any `goto`command will break it!

Here is, how I would do it (the `call`trick solves the `goto`problem):

```
set inputfile=C:\Users\locationoffile\complist.txt
for /f "delims= " %%i in (%inputfile%) do call :doit %%i
echo finihed
exit /b

:doit
echo %1
ping -n 1 %1 |find "TTL" && goto :servicecheck || goto :failed
goto :eof

:failed
echo %1 failed
goto :eof

:servicecheck
SC \\%1 QUERY ServiceName > Null
IF ERRORLEVEL 1060 GOTO INSTALL
ECHO %1 EXISTS; Checking Service State
sc \\%1 query ServiceName | findstr /i "STATE" 
goto :eof
```

`&&` works like "if no error",  `||` like "if error"

Comment: Thank you, I did not know about GOTO breaking the FOR command, that is a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

The following will allow you to check a system for a service if not installed, it installs it, if it is installed it checks and makes sure it's running it pulls the system names from an external list.

```
    @echo off

    echo Service Check STARTED on %date% at %time% 

    echo =================================================

    echo.

    setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

    set count=1

    set fnm=C:\Users\filelocation\complist1.txt

    for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (%fnm%) do (set comp=%%i

    call :SUB

    )

    :SUB

     echo !count!%1

     set /a count+=1

    Echo !comp!

    ping -n 1 %comp% | FIND "TTL="

    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO :FAILED

    SC \\!comp! QUERY <servicename> > Null

    IF ERRORLEVEL 1060 GOTO INSTALL

    ECHO <Service Name> is Installed

    GOTO STATE

    :STATE

    ECHO Checking Service State

    for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ('sc \\!comp! query <servicename> ^| findstr 

    STATE') do set CmdResult=%%a

    ECHO <Service Name> Service is !CmdResult!

    if !CmdResult!==STOPPED (

    GOTO :START

    )

    GOTO :END

    :START

    ECHO Starting Service

    psexec \\!comp! net start <servicename>

    GOTO :END

    :INSTALL

    ECHO <Service Name> is not Installed

    ECHO Installing <Service Name>

    psexec.exe -s \\!comp! \\serviceinstalllocation\filename.exe /S /v /qn

    GOTO END

    :FAILED

    ECHO Failed to connect

    :END
```